# can we remove the css selectors using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove the `CSS` selectors using `jQuery`.

I have searched in google but I couldn't get any solution. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you can override it, but you cant remove it.

Comment: why do you want to do that? what is the use case?

Comment: You can change/remove classes which will break the relation of `css` with `DOM`

Comment: Use two different css classes. And use jquery to add/remove it from the element. Second class resets the values of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response this is my css:  .bg .nav > li > a {
 color: #c5d4e3 !important;
}

Comment: Please post some fiddle

Comment: You want to remove the rule?

Comment: for different clients I am using similar css file for one client he doesn't need any color.so I am working on it around

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks,Thanks for the response but how to add /remove the css selectors...

Comment: `$("#my_element").addClass("the_class"); $("#my_element").removeClass("the_other_class");` Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp) out.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks,so my question  is can we add the selectors in a similar i have shown my css:      .bg .nav > li > a {color: #c5d4e3 !important;},Now how can i add/remove that kind of css selectors.is it possible to do??

Comment: The first answer from Raj says it already. You cannot remove it. Overriding can be done by adding css classes. That's a popular solution.

Comment: If your talking about style rule then you can check `stylesheet.deleteRule(index)` here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule

Comment: Many Thanks to each and every for your time and helping me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. You can't remove a CSS selector already defined in some CSS file. Firefox is working on this feature however, but it is not supported by other browsers.

From long comment discussion above, it seems that you want to simply *override* previously set CSS style for a specific client. A common solution is to override it:

```
$('.bg .nav > li > a').prop('style', 'color: red !important');
```

This will overwrite existing `style` attribute values. We can't use `$('').css('style', 'color: red !important');` syntax, because jQuery does not allow us to set style priority.

Community agrees the usage of `!important` should be discouraged. So, if you are the owner of the CSS file, then I would suggest removing that `!important` priority.